# Using the right environment variables when using conda build

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-build

I would like to ship c++ package (https://github.com/modsim/cadet) as anaconda package with a python wrapper. The package depends on hdf5, LAPACK and the sundials package. All of them are available as anaconda package which makes it very convenient.

Currently I build the package (without conda) using following little script:

```
#!bin/bash
export SUNDIALS_ROOT=~/anaconda3/include/sundials
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="~/Dokumente/projects/pycadet/cadet" -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="~/anaconda3/lib" -DBLA_VENDOR=Intel10_64lp ../code/
make
make install
```

I am stuck over something which is maybe really simple but reading all the documentation and watching tutorials on youtube does not help. How can I make this code generic using conda-build ? I would like to set the paths to sundials, mkl, hdf5 etc in a way that it will work on any system.

If I understood it correctly, I create the conda package on my system for e.g. linux64. It involves a call to cmake in the setup.sh script. But how does the system know where all the libraries are located on a different computer (e.g. If someone would like to install my package using conda install) ? For example:

export SUNDIALS_ROOT=~/anaconda3/include/sundials

this line obviously only works on my computer or any other on which anaconda is installed in the home directory and named anaconda3.

Any hints are highly appreciated. I am looking around in the conda build recipe examples and hopefully find an example that fits but I can`t imagine that I am the only trying to ship python wrapper for a c++ package with shared libraries.

**EDIT**

I came a bit closer to what I want to achieve using following steps:

I added:
    conda config --add channels conda-forge

And then edited the meta.yaml:

package:
        name: pycadet
        version: 3.1.2

```
build:
    number: 0
source:
    url: https://github.com/modsim/CADET/archive/v3.1.2.zip

requirements:
    build:
    - sundials
about:
    home: https://github.com/modsim/CADET
    license: GPL
summary: A package for numerical simulation of chromatography
```

All requirements are automatically downloaded and everything works until `make` crashes. The build.sh:

```
#!bin/bash
#
# The build receipy for conda 
#
#
#
#
# You can run build.sh with bash -x -e. The -x makes it echo each command that is run
# and the -e makes it exit whenever a command in the script returns nonzero exit status.
set -x -e

INCLUDE_PATH="${PREFIX}/include"
LIBRARY_PATH="${PREFIX}/lib"
CADET_PATH="${PREFIX}/cadet"

# get out of the work directory (contains downloaded cadet)
cd ..

# make the build directory (in source builds are prohibited)
mkdir build

# get into it
cd build

#export SUNDIALS_ROOT=${PREFIX}/include/sundials
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${CADET_PATH}" -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="${LIBRARY_PATH}"-DBLA_VENDOR=Intel10_64lp ${SRC_DIR} ../work/
make
make install
```

Any hints ?

Comment: Take a look at the help for environment variables set by the build process: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/environment-variables.html